# I'm having problems accessing the total price I initialized inside my if else statements

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, netbeans, jframe

How can I get the sum of the three Total prices inside the if else statements for red velvet, buttercream and vanilla? And display it in allTextArea text area?
Here's my code:

```
    double redVelvetPrice = 4.00;
    double buttercreamPrice = 7.00;
    double vanillaPrice = 3.00;
    double firstHalf = 6.00;
    double firstDozen = 12.00;
    double firstBox = 25;
    double secondHalf = 6.00;
    double secondDozen = 12.00;
    double secondBox = 25;
    double thirdHalf = 6.00;
    double thirdDozen = 12.00;
    double thirdBox = 25;

    String s1 = "";
    String s2 = "The flavors you selected is/are: \n";
    String s3 = "";
    String s4 = "";
    String s5 = "";
    String totalPrice = "";


    if (redVelvetCB.isSelected()){
        s1=s1+ " "+ redVelvetCB.getText() + '\n';

        if (firstHalfRB.isSelected()){
            s3 ="A " + firstHalfRB.getText() + " of Red Velvet Cupcakes\n = $" + redVelvetPrice * firstHalf + '\n' + '\n';

        }
        else if (firstDozenRB.isSelected()){
            s3 =firstDozenRB.getText() + " of Red Velvet Cupcakes\n = $" + redVelvetPrice * firstDozen + '\n' + '\n';

        }
        else if (firstBoxRB.isSelected()){
            s3 =firstBoxRB.getText() + " of Red Velvet Cupcakes\n = $" + redVelvetPrice * firstBox + '\n' + '\n';

        }

    }


    if (buttercreamCB.isSelected()){
        s1=s1+ " "+ buttercreamCB.getText() + '\n';

        if (secondHalfRB.isSelected()){
            s4 ="A " + secondHalfRB.getText() + " of Buttercream Cupcakes\n = $" + buttercreamPrice * secondHalf + '\n' + '\n';

        }
        else if (secondDozenRB.isSelected()){
            s4 =secondDozenRB.getText() + " of Buttercream Cupcakes\n = $" + buttercreamPrice * secondDozen + '\n' + '\n';

        }
        else if (secondBoxRB.isSelected()){
            s4 =secondBoxRB.getText() + " of Buttercream Cupcakes\n = $" + buttercreamPrice * secondBox + '\n' + '\n';

        }


    }

    if (vanillaCB.isSelected()){
        s1=s1+ " "+ vanillaCB.getText() + '\n';

        if (thirdHalfRB.isSelected()){
            s5 ="A " + thirdHalfRB.getText() + " of Vanilla Cupcakes\n = $" + vanillaPrice * thirdHalf + '\n' + '\n';

        }
        else if (thirdDozenRB.isSelected()){
            s5 =thirdDozenRB.getText() + " of Vanilla Cupcakes\n = $" + vanillaPrice * thirdDozen + '\n' + '\n';

        }
        else if (thirdBoxRB.isSelected()){
            s5 =thirdBoxRB.getText() + " of Vanilla Cupcakes\n = $" + vanillaPrice * thirdBox + '\n' + '\n';

        }

        allTextArea.setText(greeting+s2+"\n"+s1+"\n"+s3+s4+s5+"\nTotal Price is "+totalPrice+".\n"+deliv+payment+bye);
```

I tried to set the total Price equal to redVelvetPrice + butercreamPrice + vanillaPrice, but the answer would be 14.0 which is the sum of the variables I initialized outside the if else statements (4.00,7.00,3.00),
I want it to be the sum of the prices of the three after selecting the quantity of each flavor. Help me.

Comment: Where do you declare `totalPrice`?

Comment: I declared the totalPrice which is a string just after the declaration of the double values

Comment: I can't see what you're saying in your code, fix it please.

Comment: I want the totalPrice to be the sum of let's say for example (4.00*12)+(7.00*25)+(3.00*6), [redVelvetPrice*quantityselected],[buttercreamPrice*quantityselected],[vanillaPrice*quantityselected] respectively

Comment: I know, but you're not showing that on the code you've posted. I can't see  where you declared your variable.

Comment: I didn't declare the variable to store the product of the price and quantity but if you're referring to totalPrice, I've changed my code

Comment: i tried to declare the totalPrice in each of the if else statements but still the sum it shows is the same

Answer (score 1):

You should use an other data type for the `totalPrice`. It's easier to calculate with numbers than strings.

```
double totalPrice = 0f;
```

After that you add up all the different combinations in your if/else statements

```
if (firstHalfRB.isSelected()){
    s3 = "A " + firstHalfRB.getText() + " of Red Velvet Cupcakes\n = $" + redVelvetPrice * firstHalf + "\n\n";
    totalPrice += (redVelvetPrice * firstHalf);
}
else if (firstDozenRB.isSelected()){
    s3 = firstDozenRB.getText() + " of Red Velvet Cupcakes\n = $" + redVelvetPrice * firstDozen + "\n\n";
    totalPrice += (redVelvetPrice * firstDozen);
}
```

When printing the total in the TextArea you may want to format it so it only has 2 positions after decimal point:

```
String.format("%.2f", totalPrice);
```